# Calculating the area of Bounding Box

Tags: c++, opencv

Hello StackOverflowers

I have created an application that Segments an image on the basis of a predefined color using inRange function. I then draw bounding box around the detected object.

My question here is how do I determine region properties such as: area, size, height and with, center point.

Here i placed a screen dump example.....

[image]

How should i approach to retrieve region properties of these bounding boxes or any other bounding boxes that get drown.......?

```
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    findContours(mBlur, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,  CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );



     /// Approximate contours to polygons + get bounding rects and circles
  vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly( contours.size() );
  vector<Rect> boundRect( contours.size() );
  vector<Point2f>center( contours.size() );
  vector<float>radius( contours.size() );

  for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
     { approxPolyDP( Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true );
       boundRect[i] = boundingRect( Mat(contours_poly[i]) );
     }


  /// Draw polygonal contour + bonding rects
  Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( range_out.size(), CV_8UC3 );
  for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
     {
       Scalar color = Scalar(255,0,255);
       drawContours( drawing, contours_poly, i, color, 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point() );
       rectangle( drawing, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), color, 2, 8, 0 );
     }
```

Regards

Comment: How did you draw the bounding box? You'll need to show some code.

Comment: @sftrabbit I added the code that is responsible for drowing Bounding Boxes. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the area by using the built in OpenCV [function](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#contourarea). There are other functions there too to get everything you need.

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate over the 2D coordinates of the segmented shape (the thin pink line in your pictures, you can found this just checking which pixels are not black and looking into its coordinates) and store maximum and minimum X and Y found. Then, width of  is `maxX - minX` and height is `maxY - minY`

Answer (score 0):

```
void visualizeSegments(Mat& img, Mat& dst)
{
    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    findContours(img, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    dst=Mat::zeros(img.size(), CV_8UC3);
    for(int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    { 
        //Moments mu = moments(contours[i], true );
        //Point2f centroid(mu.m10/mu.m00,mu.m01/mu.m00);        
        //double area = fabs(contourArea(Mat(contours[i])));
        //vector<Point> contours_poly;
        //approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly, 3, true);
        //Rect boundRect = boundingRect(Mat(contours_poly));
        drawContours(dst, contours, i, Scalar(255,0,0), -1, 8, hierarchy);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated befor there are a set of usefull functions in [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#contourarea)
 1.  double contourArea(InputArray contour, bool oriented=false ) : to comute the area
 2.  double arcLength(InputArray curve, bool closed) : to compute the perimeter
 3.  Moments moments(InputArray array, bool binaryImage=false ) : to compute the center of gravity
 4.  void HuMoments(const Moments& m, OutputArray hu) : if you want additional properties that is usefull for classification